# background location not working when app in background xamarin forms android app when upgrade target api to 29

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, permissions, location

i have xamarin forms app that have tracking and fore ground service for background tracking working fine when set android target api level 28 but after upgrade it target api level 29 to upload app to play store no background location permission set to app so cannot get location when app in background.

and this manifest Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

and this run time request in main activity:

```
     private static string[] _initialPerms ={
        Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation,
        Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation
    };
    
 if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation) == Permission.Denied || ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.Camera) == Permission.Denied)
        {
            RequestPermissions(_initialPerms, 1337);
        }
```

thanks.

Comment: Hi ahmed gaber, even background location update not working in api level 28 too.

Comment: Hi @sameer no working fine with api 28 these only with 29 and resolved by the marked solution below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The permission **ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION** is new after Android 10.0 . Even if you have set the target version to Api 29 , but the version of support SDK in Xamarin.Android is still v28.x.x.x (Android 9.0) .So this enumeration is still unavailable in Xamarin.Android now . What you need is just to wait the update of the support SDK .

[image]

In your case , **ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION** will compatible with old version .
If the application apply for **ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION** or **ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION**, the system will automatically add a permission **ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION** during building.

===========================Update===============================

On Android 10 (API level 29) and higher, you must declare the **ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION** permission in your app's manifest in order to request ***background location access*** at runtime. On earlier versions of Android, when your app receives foreground location access, it automatically receives background location access as well.

```
<manifest ... >
  <!-- Required only when requesting background location access on
       Android 10 (API level 29) and higher. -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

More info refer to android document [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions).

Comment: in these case i face program withe android 10 devices no permission for all time only generate permission for only when using app 
Is there a solution to this problem. thanks

Comment: @ahmedgaber On Android 10 (API level 29) and higher, you must declare the **ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION** permission in your app's manifest in order to request background location access at runtime.On earlier versions of Android, when your app receives foreground location access, it automatically receives background location access as well. You can have a look at official document [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#background). And I have updated the answer with this.

Comment: They will not be updating this package. You are supposed to upgrade to AndroidX.

ref. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/androidx

Once I find all the steps I'll post an answer

Answer (score 0):

From Android 10, background location came as an independent resource. Apps have to request explicitly this permission besides the foreground one.

```
@TargetApi(29)
private fun Context.checkLocationPermissionAPI29(locationRequestCode : Int) {
    if (checkSinglePermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) &&
        checkSinglePermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) &&
        checkSinglePermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)) return
    val permList = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, 
                           Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                           Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
    requestPermissions(permList, locationRequestCode)
    
}

private fun Context.checkSinglePermission(permission: String) : Boolean {
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}
```

Comment: CCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION not found inside Manifest.permission

Comment: Maybe for you it's a `Manifest.Permission.AccessBackgroundLocation`

Comment: these only permissions related to location found inside  Manifest.Permission.
               Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation,
            Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation,
            Manifest.Permission.AccessLocationExtraCommands,
            Manifest.Permission.LocationHardware,
            Manifest.Permission.AccessMockLocation